# JsonProperty and lombok: Renaming is not done

Tags: java, spring-boot, jackson, lombok

I have a class annotat with @Data and @JsonProperty like in this example:

```
@Data
@Jacksonized
public class Request {

  private Request.RequestRoot root;

  @Data
  @Jacksonized
  public class RequestRoot {

    @JsonProperty("AEND-DAT")
    private LocalDate aenderungsdatum;

    @JsonProperty("ANR-SL")
    private String anredeSl;
  }
}
```

This object is passed to a REST call and converted to JSON. But the JsonProperty is ignored, the fields are not named like this porperty says. It just ends in aenderungsdatum ant not AEND-DAT.
But I am required to use the names given in JsonProperty because the REST interface only accepts this values.

Am I missing anything?

Comment: How do you serialize your POJOs? Is it plain Spring? Or some other frameworks involved?
PS: lombok should give you a warning on `@Jacksonized`, because that annotation has no effect without `@(Super)Builder`. You can remove it if you do not intend to use a builder for Jackson's instantiation.

Comment: I've ran your code and it's working as expected (Lombok=1.18.22, Jackson=2.13.1). Please post your ObjectMapper configuration and the version of Jackson/Lombok

Answer (score 0):

Fix it in this way:-

@NoArgsConstructor

@AllArgsConstructor

public class Token {

```
@Setter(onMethod = @__(@JsonSetter(value = "access_token"))) 

@Getter(onMethod = @__(@JsonGetter(value = "accessToken"))) 

private String accessToken;
```

}